# SQL Server Function like behavior in a query without creating a function?

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a situation where I can save a lot of repeated text in a query if I use a function however at this site I do not have rights to create a function on the server.

It there a way to have a function defined in the body of the query and then call it from the query itself?

Hopefully I post the following stripped down code correctly. The real query calls two functions, count by year and revenue by year.

```
-- Function 
alter function PetRockCountByYear 
     (@Company varchar(50), @DateFrom varchar(20), @DateTo varchar(20))
RETURNS varchar(50)  
AS
begin
    return (select isnull( SUM( transact.qty ), 0) 
            from TRANSACT 
            inner join CATALOG on transact.ITEM_NO = catalog.ITEM_NO
            where transact.TRAN_DATE >= @DateFrom 
              and transact.TRAN_DATE <= @DateTo  
              and transact.ITEM_NO = 'PetRock'
              and @Company = transact.company 
              and transact.ITEM_NO = catalog.ITEM_NO)  
end

-- Simplified Query Below
select distinct 
    company.account, company.COMPANY,
    company.STATUS, company.code,
    -- Report counts from 1970 - 2015
    (select dbo.PetRockCountByYear(company.COMPANY, '01/01/1970', '12/31/1970') ) as '#1970',
    (select dbo.PetRockCountByYear( company.COMPANY , '01/01/1971', '12/31/1971') ) as '#1971'
from 
    TRANSACT 
Inner join 
    invoices on transact.inv_no = invoices.inv_no
Inner join 
    COMPANY on invoices.COMPANY = company.company
where 
    ITEM_NO = 'PetRock' 
order by 
    company.ACCOUNT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no temporary functions in SQL-Server T-SQL, you need to have `CREATE FUNCTION` rights on the database look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx#Anchor_2 And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx#Anchor_0